# Devices able to run Docker engine

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, internet-of-things

I am making some database app and stuff and I need to run MySQL database somewhere. I was wandering what to choose, because I need it to run all day and I want to run it as docker container...so I was thinking of Raspberry pi, but is it the cheapest way to do it? Aren't there some smaller and more simple devices able to handle docker engine?

Thank you.

Comment: (1) Why don't you run it within a VM (or container) on an existent server? (2) What about a cloud managed service? Some are free: in terms of cost, you can't possibly do better.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer, cloud is a good idea, but I need it to run in my local network. And about the VM...I actually don't have any server yet.

Comment: Need more information about this database app.

Comment: No, the database app isn't the point. I am just asking if there are some cheaper devices than raspberry pi, able to run docker, thats all. The app is the reason why I need it, but I want device not only for specific purpose, but generally for docker containers.